# Slurm: Show node state of POWERED_DOWN nodes in a cloud scheduling system

Tags: slurm

**Problem Description**

Let's say I have two `CLOUD` nodes running. Now for some reason they fail and go to `DOWN` and they `POWER_DOWN`. Now `sinfo` will no longer detect them. You can still change the node state using `sudo scontrol update NodeName=$NODE_NAME state=$BECOME_STATE reason=$REASON` and there are clear signs that a node state is still held. For example: Slurm will not schedule jobs to `DOWN` nodes even if they are `POWER_DOWN`, so the node being `DOWN` must be held by slurm somewhere.

Using `scontrol show $NODE_NAME` also doesn't work when the node is in `POWER_DOWN`.

**Question**

Is there any possibility to retrieve the node state of a node which is not `POWER_UP` i.e. not shown by `sinfo` due to not being "online"?

**Additional Information**

In our [Cloud Scheduling](https://slurm.schedmd.com/elastic_computing.html) instances are created once they are needed and deleted once they are no longer deleted. This means that slurm stores that a node is `DOWN` while no real instance behind it exists anymore. If that node wouldn't be marked `DOWN` and a job would be scheduled towards it at a later time, it would simply start an instance and run on that new instance. I am just stating this to be maximum explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding

```
PrivateData=cloud
```

to your slurm configuration. This is only mentioned here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/elastic_computing.html

Powered down nodes will then be displayed with a `~` postfix.